# Check if value is in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to check if a specific value is anywhere in a data frame.

I know the `%in%` operator should allow me to do this, but it doesn't seem to work the way I would expect when applying to a whole data frame:

```
A = data.frame(B=c(1,2,3,4), C=c(5,6,7,8))
1 %in% A

[1] FALSE
```

But if I apply this to the specific column the value is in it works the way I expect:

```
1 %in% A$C

[1] TRUE
```

What is the proper way of checking if a value is anywhere in a data frame?

Comment: `1 %in% as.matrix(A)` ? Which, of course, makes sense if all the columns of A are numbers...

Comment: @digEmAll, `"1" %in% as.character(as.matrix(A))` may work in all cases but I don't know how much better that is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do:

```
any(A==1)
#[1] TRUE
```

OR with `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("|", A==1)
```

OR

```
length(which(A==1))>0
```

OR

```
is.element(1,unlist(A))
```

Comment: Although all these work, only the first of them makes it clear what the code does.

Answer (score 10):

To find the location of that value you can do f.ex:

```
which(A == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
```

Answer (score 8):

Or simply

```
sum(A == 1) > 0
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Clearer would be `any(A == 1)`

Answer (score 6):

Loop through the variables with `sapply`, then use `any`.

```
any(sapply(A, function(x) 1 %in% x))
[1] TRUE
```

or following digEmAll's comment, you could use `unlist`, which takes a list (data.frame) and returns a vector.

```
1 %in% unlist(A)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick to understanding why your first attempt doesn't work, really comes down to understanding what a data frame is - namely a list of vectors of equal length. What you're trying to do here is not check if that list of vectors matches your condition, but checking if the values in those vectors matches the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`any(A == 1)`

Returns FALSE or TRUE