# Replacing a dataframe entry with the last value in a listed entry in R

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like the below:

```
BaseRating    contRating Participant
5,4,6,3,2,4       5        01       
4                 4        01
```

I would first like to run some code that looks to see whether there are any commas in the dataframe, and returns a column number of where that is. I have tried some of the solutions in the questions below, which don't seem to work when looking for a comma instead of a string/whole value? I'm probably missing something simple here but any help appreciated!

[Selecting data frame rows based on partial string match in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-data-frame-rows-based-on-partial-string-match-in-a-column)

[Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

[Check if value is in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233798/check-if-value-is-in-data-frame/43234188)

Having determined whether there are commas in my data, I then want to extract just the last number in the list separated by commas in that entry, and replace the entry with that value. For instance, I want the first row in the BaseRating column to become '4' because it is last in that list.

Is there a way to do this in R without manually changing the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is bellow.

**EXPLANATION**

In what follows, I will explain the `regex` expression used in `str_extract` function, as asked for by @milsandhills:

1. The symbol `|` in the middle means the logical `OR` operator.
2. We use that because `BaseRating` can have multiple numbers or only one number — hence the need to use `|`, to treat each case separately.
3. The left-hand side of `|` means a number formed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), which starts (`^`) and finishes the string (`$`).
4. The right-hand side of `|` means a number formed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), which finishes the string (`$`). And `(?<=\\,)` is used to guarantee that the number is preceded by a comma.

You can find more details at the [stringr cheat sheet](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf).

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  BaseRating = c("5,4,6,3,2,4", "4"),
  contRating = c(5L, 4L),
  Participant = c(1L, 1L)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(BaseRating = sapply(BaseRating, 
         function(x) str_extract(x, "^\\d+$|(?<=\\,)\\d+$") %>% as.integer))

#>   BaseRating contRating Participant
#> 1          4          5           1
#> 2          4          4           1
```

---

Or:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(BaseRating, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(contRating, Participant) %>% 
  summarise(BaseRating = last(BaseRating), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  relocate(BaseRating, .before = 1)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   BaseRating contRating Participant
#>        <int>      <int>       <int>
#> 1          4          4           1
#> 2          4          5           1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! My actual data frame has a lot more columns than in my user-friendly example, so I wondered if there is a quicker way than grouping by all my existing columns?

Comment: Maybe the new solution I just added to my answer is what you are looking for, @milsandhills.

Comment: Your second option works wonderfully. Could you perhaps explain a bit more about what the code within the str_extract function is actually doing, as I'm a bit puzzled by all the symbols?

Comment: I have just added an explanation to my answer, @milsandhills. Hope that helps you! If you have any further question, please do not hesitate and ask me.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

If we want a quick option, we can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$BaseRating <- as.numeric(trimws(df$BaseRating, whitespace = ".*,"))
```

-output

```
> df
  BaseRating contRating Participant
1          4          5           1
2          4          4           1
```

---

Or another option is `stri_extract_last`

```
library(stringi)
df$BaseRating <- as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(df$BaseRating, "\\d+"))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(BaseRating = c("5,4,6,3,2,4", "4"), contRating = 5:4, 
    Participant = c(1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```